# Delete object of class with all its references

Tags: python, object, oop, memory

I have a class that takes a text file as input. When I provide certain input I want to delete all instances of the object and create a new instance.  This input represent that config file is updated and application needs to be started again.
This is what I've till now.

```
def main():

    _config_path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else ""
    app = Application(_config_path)
    is_brk = False
    while True:
        query = input()
        if query.startswith('__'):
            is_brk = True
            break
        # do_action() #This does some action
    if is_brk:
        # this does not work as some of objects in Application are singleton and not got 
        # deleted.
        # this is what I've tried
        del app
        import gc
        gc.collect()
        main() # this
```

The error I'm getting is:
`2021-10-26 06:04:53,981 __init__ ERROR Error in Application __init__(): An instance has already been created. Creation of second instance of singleton class MySingletonClass is not allowed`

Any suggestion what can be done in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you call main recursively? It looks like it would make more sense to place Application creation in another loop outside the input loop.

Comment: maybe first get `query` and check it - and later create `Application` only once. OR check if `Application` has method to replace `path` without recreating `Application`

Comment: @furas Application take `config` file as input. And then allow user to execute multiple queries. But if user has made certain changes in `config` then I want user to restart application with certain special `query`

Comment: I don't know what you have in `Application` but normally it wouldn't need any `del` and `gc.collect()` - so bettter show what is in `Application`. Your problem is that it uses `MySingletonClass` . Better create in `Application` function which can get new config without creating `Application` again. If you use `config_path` in `__init__` to set values then move it in separated function - i.e `reset()` - and run this function in _init__` And then you could use `app.reset()` again to change it without creating `Application` again.